# Problem with WCF and SSL

Tags: wcf

I am having problems getting a web service working using SSL and WCF.

**If I check in IIS the "Require SSL" seeting then I get this error:**

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>
> Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/36097441 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: Service
>   'ISS.MS.WebServices.MessageDispatch.MessageDispatchWebService' has
>   zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   service element matching the service name could be found in the
>   configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the
>   service element.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Service
>   'ISS.MS.WebServices.MessageDispatch.MessageDispatchWebService' has
>   zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   service element matching the service name could be found in the
>   configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the
>   service element.

**However if I uncheck it, the page loads fine in the browser but then I get this error
when I try calling it.**

> Service 'ISS.MS.WebServices.MessageDispatch.MessageDispatchWebService'
>   has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be
>   because no configuration file was found for your application, or
>   because no service element matching the service name could be found in
>   the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the
>   service element.

This is the configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="ISS.MS.WebServices.MessageDispatchWcfService">
            <endpoint
                address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_MS2" 
                contract="ISS.MS.WebServices.IMessageDispatchWcfService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBinding_MS2" >
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1048576" />
               <security mode="Transport">
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I can get it working perfectly using normal HTTP, but HTTPs doesn't work.

I am guessing its either an IIS setting or WCF configuration issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, the name of the service and contract was not correct...how embarrassing.

Anyone know why it would still work over HTTP even it these are incorrect?

Comment: Thank you.  This just ended about 8 hours of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

(About "multipleSiteBindingsEnabled"): To enable multiple IIS bindings per site for a service, set this property to true. Notice that multiple site binding is supported only for the HTTP protocol.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicehostingenvironmentsection.multiplesitebindingsenabled.aspx

try this

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```